# Present existing PDF to client using Adobe Reader?

Tags: .net, pdf

I have an existing PDF on the web server that I want to present to the client in Adobe Reader, which they do have it installed.  I have the following code and it works when I run in Visual Studio, but when I deploy to server and test - nothing happens.

Here is the code

```
 //Print PDF
        System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(filePath);
        Process.Start(filePath);
```

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: ps - I did verify path and file is there.

Comment: Is that path to the file on the server? looks like you are downloading the file but not doing anything with what was downloaded. You would need to save the buffer data to disk and use the path to that data when starting the process

Comment: Yes, it's the path to the .pdf file on the server.  This does work locally when I run it in VS.

Comment: Does it still work with this line alone `Process.Start(filePath);` and the above two other lines removed? Show an *example* of the file path.

Comment: Yes, it does work remove the two lines.  But I think what the problem is, that Process.Start(filepath) is just to open the file as part of the clients (my machines) default PDF application.  Once you try from the web server, the code somehow needs to be told to open it on the clients machine using the clients PDF reader.

Comment: I asked you to check if calling process along worked in order to confirm a suspicion. Is file path a path to disk or a url? you are going to have to show some more code and try to clear up what you are trying to achieve. as it currently stands it is still too broad to provide you with a direct solution to your problem. I have some ideas but would need you to clarify your problem